# Is there a function instead of a line.new() or label.new() that can be used in the strategy?

Tags: pine-script

Problem 1: In the study, the variables `fibEntry` and `fibProfit` give weird values from the beginning. Those values are way below the bar set. When the conditions from the script are true then the variables give the correct values.

Problem 2: In the strategy,  the script triggers entry at the `open` bar value because of that weird value of `fibEntry` which is way below the bar set. And on every other day the script triggers `fibProfit` at the close bar value.

Problem 3: In the strategy, even when the conditions are true, the script is ignoring that.

I can't use drawings because I need those values for the strategy.

I did try with:

`strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true, when=barstate.isconfirmed and fibEntry)`

and

`strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true, when=dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1] and fibEntry)`

Here is the code:

```
//@version=4

study(title="first baby study",overlay=true)

// Step 1. Highs and lows

pHigh = pivothigh(1,1)
pLow = pivotlow(1,1)

// Step 2. Fibonacci

// Step 2.1 Fibonacci Top

fibTop = 0.00

if pHigh > pHigh[2] or pHigh > pHigh[3] or pHigh > pHigh[4] or pHigh > pHigh[5]

    if close[1] > open[1]

        fibTop := close[1]

    if open[1] > close[1]

        fibTop := open[1]

// Step 2.2. Fibonacci Bottom

fibBottom = 0.00

if pLow > pLow[2] or pLow > pLow[3] or pLow > pLow[4] or pLow > pLow[5]

    if close[1] > open[1]

        fibBottom := open[1]

    if open[1] > close[1]

        fibBottom := close[1]

// Step 2.3. Fibonacci 0.272 - Entry Levl

var float fibEntry = na

if fibBottom[1] 
    fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[1])
else
    if fibBottom[2] 
        fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[2])
    else
        if fibBottom[3] 
            fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[3])
        else
            if fibBottom[4]
                fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[4])
            else
                if fibBottom[5]
                    fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[5])

// Step 2.4. Fibonacci -0.272 - Take Profit Level

var float fibProfit = na

if fibBottom[1]
    fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[1]) * 0.272 + fibTop
else
    if fibBottom[2]
        fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[2]) * 0.272 + fibTop
    else
        if fibBottom[3]
            fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[3]) * 0.272 + fibTop
        else
            if fibBottom[4]
                fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[4]) * 0.272 + fibTop
            else
                if fibBottom[5]
                    fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[5]) * 0.272 + fibTop

// // Step 3. Enter Trade

// strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true, when=fibEntry)

// // Step 4. Take Profit

// strategy.close(id="Long", when=fibProfit)


// Step 5. Plotting

plot(fibEntry, color=#ffe504)
plot(fibProfit, color=#00ff0a)    
plot(fibTop, color=color.green, offset=-1)
plot(fibBottom, color=color.red, offset=-1)
plot(pHigh, color=color.green, transp=50,style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, offset=-1)
plot(pLow, color=color.red, transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, offset=-1)
```

This is my first study/strategy, hopefully, someone will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably get you closer to your goal. We init the variables to `na` and make sure they come out of the main `if` blocks with a value:

```
// Step 2.1 Fibonacci Top

float fibTop = na
if pHigh > pHigh[2] or pHigh > pHigh[3] or pHigh > pHigh[4] or pHigh > pHigh[5]
    if close[1] > open[1]
        fibTop := close[1]
    else
        fibTop := open[1]

// Step 2.2. Fibonacci Bottom

float fibBottom = na
if pLow > pLow[2] or pLow > pLow[3] or pLow > pLow[4] or pLow > pLow[5]
    if close[1] > open[1]
        fibBottom := open[1]
    else
        fibBottom := close[1]
```

[image]